# Jekyll Liquid tags not being replaced

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have the below in a `.css` file for my website, yet the exact same thing is showing up when I try to generate the site. That is the Liquid tags are not being replaced but the below is being treated like plaintext. How would I fix this?

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Examplefont';
    src: url({{ '/css/ef/eot/Examplefont-Light.eot');
    src: local('Examplefont Sans Light'),
         url({{ '/css/ef/eot/Examplefont-Light.eot' | absolute_url }} format('embedded-opentype'),
         url({{ '/css/ef/woff/Examplefont-Light.woff' | absolute_url }} format('woff'),
         url({{ '/css/ef/ttf/Examplefont-Light.ttf' | absolute_url }} format('truetype');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Jekyll only processes liquid in files that have front matter, but you can just add it in empty:

```
---
---

@font-face{
  font-family: 'Examplefont';
  src: url({{ '/css/ef/eot/Examplefont-Light.eot' | absolute_url }});
  src: local('Examplefont Sans Light'),
     url({{ '/css/ef/eot/Examplefont-Light.eot' | absolute_url }} format('embedded-opentype'),
     url({{ '/css/ef/woff/Examplefont-Light.woff' | absolute_url }} format('woff'),
     url({{ '/css/ef/ttf/Examplefont-Light.ttf' | absolute_url }} format('truetype');
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

By the way, you're also missing the closing end braces on your first `src` line.